# Why is a review pending, but I can find nothing to review?

Tags: discussion

I seem to have some interpretations mixed up. Hope you can help.

Two screen shots from my main genealogy.se page follow; I have refreshed the page multiple times.

As I interpret the first screen image, there is a review pending. As I interpret the second, there is no review pending. (I have no pending notifications, either.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because *you* suggested that edit - and you can't review your own suggestion!

It's a little bit confusing, I admit - but it simplifies the logic to display that notification.

Answer (score 0):

Might there also have been something lurking under moderator tools?

Comment: Fairly sure Shog9 got it. I had just entered a tag edit, so it was almost certainly my own entry that was being flagged. Since I'd entered the information, there wasn't something there for me to review.